# import and alias a static method from a class

Tags: php, import, alias

I am trying to alias a static method from a utility/helper class, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) does not give anything regarding static methods and using those defined there doesn't work for static methods (as it seems so).

So say I have this class:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class HTTP {

    public static function extract_path_from_url( string $url ) {
        $parsed_url = wp_parse_url( $url );
        if ( ! isset( $parsed_url['path'] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return (string) $parsed_url['path'];

    }

}
```

then trying to use it on a different file:

```
<?php

echo \App\Helpers\HTTP::extract_path_from_url( 'http://example.com/test' );
```

that one above works

but trying to alias it:

```
<?php

use \App\Helpers\HTTP\extract_path_from_url as extract_path;

echo extract_path( 'http://example.com/test' );
```

would output

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function App\Helpers\HTTP\extract_path_from_url()
```

even:

```
<?php

use \App\Helpers\HTTP::extract_path_from_url as extract_path;

echo extract_path( 'http://example.com/test' );
```

shows this weird error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

Is this possible?

Regards,

Comment: You can `use` either __class__ or __standalone function__, but not a method of a class. That's all.

Comment: @u_mulder I thought I can with PHP5.6+ `use function ...` http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: __function__ is a standalone function. Method of class is __not a function__.

Comment: It would be nice if one could do this `use \App\Helpers\HTTP::extract_path_from_url as extract_path;` But alas no sauce.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix true

Comment: There is a RFC that would allow to use static methods as function. 
If you want to vote/support it. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/use-static-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliasing doesn't magically convert methods into functions, try this instead

```
<?php
    use \App\Helpers\HTTP as extract_path;
    echo extract_path::extract_path_from_url( 'http://example.com/test' );
```

Also (it should go without saying) when you alias this only affects the namespace and class name, not methods of the class.  These are generally used for 1 of 2 things.  Resolving naming conflicts

```
 use NamespaceOne\Someclass;
 use NamespaceTwo\Someclass as SecondClass;
```

If these were both put without an alias then using

```
 Someclass::method()
```

Would be ambiguous.

The second thing they can be used for is if you need a lot of classes imported from one namespace.  Such as this:

```
use App\Exceptions\NoFile;
use App\Exceptions\FileSize;
use App\Exceptions\FileType;

throw new NoFile();
throw new FileSize();
throw new FileType();
```

Can be done this way:

```
use App\Exceptions as E;

throw new E\NoFile();
throw new E\FileSize();
throw new E\FileType();
```

Which is not only shorter, but easier to maintain if you change the namespace you have to only change it for the alias and then all is good.  So in short it's not really intended for what you want to use it for.

**Wrap it**

You can always make a wrapper for it:

```
if(!function_exists('extract_path_from_url')){
     function extract_path_from_url($url){
        return \App\Helpers\HTTP::extract_path_from_url($url);
     }
}
```

And then call it to your hearts content.  Performance wise you do have an extra call by wrapping it, but generally wrappers make it easier to maintain. For example if you rename that method or class, you can change it in the wrapper and everything is good.  So there is an argument to be made for either option.

You don't have to check if the function exists, but depending on how your overall system works it may not be a bad idea, so I included it in the example just for the sake of completeness.  Personally in a case like this, I don't see any issue putting it right in the same file with the class, just remember to load it. If you are using autoloading the functions won't be included unless you manually load the file or otherwise force it to autoload.  Assuming nothing else uses the class first, of course.

One method I have used in the past that I really like, is to make a file named `http_functions` (classname + _functions) and then add a static method to the class that registers the functions:

```
  class HTTP {
      public static function register_functions(){
          require 'http_functions.php';
      }
  }
```

Then when you call `HTTP::register_functions()` it autoloads `HTTP` class and includes all the functional wrappers.  In fact I do this very thing in my really super awesome debug print class (queue shameless plug) https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Debug

Just some thoughts, enjoy!

Comment: thanks mate, your approached on the 2nd block is good, the first block is ugly though.

Comment: The first block was necessary to show how to properly use an alias.  Personally I only use them on exception classes.  But I like to have one class per exception so it get's tiring putting the namespace in over and over.  Which is really what they are for.  Well that and naming conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to use a namespaced `helpers.php` file and define 'simple' functions in it, which simply pass through arguments.

```
// lib/My/Deeply/Nested/Namespace/MyClass.php

<?php

namespace My\Deeply\Nested\Namespace;

class MyClass
{
    public static function aVeryUsefulFunction(string $var): string
    {
        // ...Do some stuff

        return $magic;
    }
}
```

```
// lib/helpers.php

namespace App;

use My\Deeply\Nested\Namespace\MyClass;

function doMagic(...$args)
{
    return MyClass::aVeryUsefulFunction(...$args);
}
```

```
// templates/my-view.php

<?php use function App\doMagic; ?>

<div>I am doing <?= doMagic('magic') ?>!</div>
```

Note that by using the spread operator `...$args` in my 'pass through' function I can change the requirements of the 'target' function without having to update it in two places.

This will break IDE completion, as it will only know to suggest `...$args` rather than `string $var`.  I don't know of a way to docblock a function to tell it to read parameters from *another* function.

Answer (score 1):

As manual says you can import via `use` classes, functions and constants. Method of a class (even a static one) is **not a function**.

So, for example you have:

```
namespace My\Super\NameSpace;

const MY_CONST = 42;

class MyClass { 

    public function do() { /* code */ }  // this is NOT a function
    public static function doStatic() { /* code */ }  // this is NOT a function too

}

function my_function() { /* code */ }  // this is function
```

In some other file you can write:

```
namespace YaNamespace;

use const My\Super\NameSpace\MY_CONST;
use My\Super\NameSpace\MyClass;
use function My\Super\NameSpace\my_function as func_alias;
```

And that's all items you can import with `use`.

Comment: ugh, that's a bummer. _Method of a class (even a static one) is not a function._

Comment: asking the same question too, who and why for the downvote? http://prntscr.com/l07h9e

Comment: thanks you're totally right, this `use function ...` confused me. thanks!

Comment: You can also alias a sub section of the namespace `And that's all items you can import with use`  I show this in my answer.  I only mention this for completeness.  Otherwise it's a good description of how namespace aliases work.